# Apply a custom function to each group in a dataframe which adds a new column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which needs a custom function applied to it for each group, which has a calculation based on 2 of the columns. This custom function returns a vector which would update/add a column to that "group" in the dataframe. Ultimately I need to apply the function over each group to create a complete new column in the dataframe

The problem I am having is getting the output from my function to find the correct grouped rows. The only approach I have found which allows me to "calculate" on 2 values of my dataframe just adds the output to the original dataframe without rearranging it to merge correctly

This is a simplified version of what I am doing, but I am having the same issue in the real problem:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'),
                 item = c('x','x','y','y','z','z','y','y'),
                val1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                val2 = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))

test <- function(x) x$val1 * x$val2

> transform(df, 
            t = unlist(unname(
                  lapply(split(df, list(df$name, df$item)), test))))

  name item val1 val2  t
1    a    x    1    1  1
2    a    x    2    2  4
3    a    y    3    1  3
4    a    y    4    2  8
5    b    z    5    1  7
6    b    z    6    2 16
7    b    y    7    1  5
8    b    y    8    2 12
```

The following method would work if there is a way of passing 2 columns of values to the ave function (val1 and val2)

```
test1 <- function(x) x * 10
> transform(df, t1 = ave(val1, name, item, FUN = function(x) test1(x)))
  name item val1 val2 t1
1    a    x    1    1 10
2    a    x    2    2 20
3    a    y    3    1 30
4    a    y    4    2 40
5    b    z    5    1 50
6    b    z    6    2 60
7    b    y    7    1 70
8    b    y    8    2 80
```

edit: updated the example to more closely reflect the structure of the real problem data (each group has multiple lines)

edit2: the solution works if my data were exactly organised in the same order as the factors get grouped

Would prefer a base R approach similar to the above, correcting for whatever mistakes I am making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by()` to apply a function to a data frame split by a factor.

```r
test <- function(x, y) x * y

by(df, df$name, \(dat) {
  transform(dat, t = test(val1, val2))
}) |> do.call(what = rbind)

#   name item val1 val2  t
# 1    a    x    1    1  1
# 2    a    y    2    2  4
# 3    b    z    3    1  3
# 4    b    x    4    2  8
# 5    c    y    5    1  5
# 6    c    x    6    2 12
# 7    d    y    7    1  7
# 8    d    z    8    2 16
```

The way you define `test` is not recommended. It restricts the column names of its input to be `val1` and `val2`.

```r
# Bad
test <- function(x) x$val1 * x$val2
```

Comment: `do.call()` is faster than `Reduce`, see my update. `\(dat)` is a shortcut of `function(dat)` that defines an anonymous function. If your real data is large and you pursue efficiency, you may need a `data.table` solution, not `base`.

Comment: **This works**. The speed is rather slow though on my test data set of 175k rows (and I'll need to apply it on significantly larger sets). In my research trying to resolve this problem I did read that Reduce was slow - is there something that can replace that part of the solution?

Comment: Updated solution is much faster. Appreciate the explanation

Comment: does this solution group by both ```name``` and ```item```, or only ```name```? If the latter, can you update it to group by both as per my (unclear) original post

Comment: @DavidAlexander You can just replace `df$name` with `list(df$name, df$item)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` into a list of data.frames, then `lapply` the custom function, and finally `rbind` everything back together

```
df |>
    split(list(df$name, df$item)) |>
    lapply(\(x) cbind.data.frame(x, t = x[["val1"]] * x[["val2"]])) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _)

      name item val1 val2  t
a.x.1    a    x    1    1  1
a.x.2    a    x    2    2  4
a.y.3    a    y    3    1  3
a.y.4    a    y    4    2  8
b.y.7    b    y    7    1  7
b.y.8    b    y    8    2 16
b.z.5    b    z    5    1  5
b.z.6    b    z    6    2 12
```

A potentially faster option, with dplyr's frontend to `data.table`, `dtplyr`:

```
library(dtplyr)

df2 <-  df |>
    lazy_dt() #create the lazy_dt object

df2 |> #use regular dplyr sythax
    group_by(name, item) |>
    mutate(t = val1 * val2) |>
    as_tibble() #collect the result as a regular dplyr object

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  name  item   val1  val2     t
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     x         1     1     1
2 a     x         2     2     4
3 a     y         3     1     3
4 a     y         4     2     8
5 b     z         5     1     5
6 b     z         6     2    12
7 b     y         7     1     7
8 b     y         8     2    16
```

Comment: This works equally well as the other answer I marked as correct

Comment: substituting `do.call` for `Reduce` was probably enough, but if we need a speed up, we can use data.table. The speed up is particularly relevant if we have too many groups

Comment: Are these solutions grouping by the combination of both ```name``` and ```item```, or only ```name```?

Comment: only name, did I get it wrong? I can  update to group by two columns

Comment: updated the answer. the df is now grouped by name and item

Comment: Yes please. I realise now that I wasn't clear enough in my post - although you can see I do pass both of them in my solution (which doesn't work). Also I may need to-recheck the first answer too, in case that also doesn't group by both

Comment: please tell us about the performance of the solutions, I would especially like to know if solution 2 is fast enough

Comment: Sol 2 is significantly faster than Sol 1 (50x). It's also much faster than the other post I marked as correct. However, I did say I was preferring base solutions if possible so have left it

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking. I never actually needed to use dtplyr, so I was curious about performance. The answer from @DarrenTsai is really excellent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252453/discussion-between-david-alexander-and-guedesbf).